# Angular assets folder is being searched at the root of tomcat server

Tags: angular, tomcat, deployment

I have a angular project that I have to deploy using tomcat. The angular files get build in `dist/project-ui/`  folder. I copied the `project-ui` folder to `webapps` folder of tomcat and started the server. The UI loads up but the `assets` folder of the `project-ui` is is being searched at `http://localhost:8080/assets/...` while the actual path would be `http://localhost:8080/project-ui/assets/...`

Initially the files such as `main...` and `polyfills..` in `project-ui` were not being loaded and I was shown a blank screen. So I tried running the command:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /project-ui/ --deploy-url /project-ui/
```

This made some of the UI elements appear but the `assets` folder is still being searched at the root of tomcat.

This is the error that I am shown:

[image]

Update:
I moved the assets directory to `webapps/assets` just to check if it works. It does work. I need to somehow change the path to `assets` folder to `project-ui/assets`

Comment: Could you show us how you refer to the asset folder in your template?

Comment: I am not very familiar with angular, could you please tell me which file you wish to see? @TheAngularGuy

Answer (score 0):

Once angular build the project, check the dist folder for the directory structure. You will notice that the asset folder is parallel to index.html. So you need to provide the path to your assets considering this folder structure.

So in your template you can refer to your assets as below -

```
<img src="./assets/images/folder.png" />
```